# Typescript weird type inference {} when checking null or undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

After we upgraded from typescript 4.9.3 to 5.0.2 we faced following error during asserting types.

Does anybody know why function "wontWorking" won't work?
I would expect that this function inference `v` as `Record<string, any>` as well but instead it inference it as `{}` and also after calling `assertRecord` it still keeps `{}` as type..

```
function assertRecord(v: unknown): asserts v is Record<string, any> {
    if(typeof v !== 'object' || v === null) throw new Error ();
}


function wontWorking (v: unknown) : null | any{

  // v = unkown
  if ( v === null || v === undefined ) return null; //checking

  // v = {}
  assertRecord(v)

  // v = {}
  var s = v.fileName // ERROR: Property 'fileName' does not exist on type '{}'.
  return s
}
wontWorking({fileName: 1231321});


function working (v: unknown) : null | any{

  // v = unkown
  // not checking

  // v = unknown
  assertRecord(v)

  // v = Record<string, any>
  var s = v.fileName
  return s
}
working({fileName: 1231321});


function isNil ( v: unknown) : v is null | undefined{
    return v === null || v === undefined
}

function workingWithCheck (v: unknown) : null | any{

  // v = unkown
  if ( isNil(v) ) return null; //checking 

  // v = unknown
  assertRecord(v)

  // v = Record<string, any>
  var s = v.fileName
  return s
}
workingWithCheck({fileName: 1231321});
```

We expect that `wontWorking`function will inference type of `v` after calling `assertRecord` as `Record<string,any>` as well.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoCUMRxYAmAFAG4Bci4A1mHAO5gCU1amOqi5iM3+QiQA8qKFhhgA5gBoUYAJ4A+RAG8AUAEgYwUlAUAHDHGA9EAQgC8lxAHI4AIwBWBKLcQAfD2es2wIABsAlkQoAAssJkQwDEZEAFEsSKxEUhYAbnUAX3Vc0EhYBERGBCgAdSJaSSlUqhoweiZWRGp-IM95BQ11REQAej6fetomnr5TUh9raMCAz29eX3riDGBJDGJEEKwMKBAsJDaA9P6+iDCCKulc3oGh1Rzejmw8AiIychYb0-vHnmQUtwbOQAHRrAIYAByyAAthgfvFcLgAPK4agABUiRhwCjs4KhsIw7mIcAw3AYUEQGAAHvxKUV9EY7A9bCCxjs9gdEKhsuoSmBypVqqRVPjoXDqABGABMAGZJbLpZKshlcup8tB4EgSlgrjUKNQ6AxmCFWrMOshFN1boNFsNRjbonBKedLtVvnc7UaHSh0C9BO8KF8xp7EDYAyIxBJpHJLcoxuQAdywzwwTAIeKMOzdvskDycjq9SKxYSpXKFUqVZk8uBNUV+JD06keIaGsbmtRePwZu1vOAVmsYsQNL1ehzc1M-OavJPlqt1sReera4VtULpGUYOEAMIXCC0Wqtxomlo9ubeOPWn5eho+nTNhvpoNbRDjrlHE4DV376qID22lNvWYMZnhwCMPmDR07XA0RxGqWNFCUBMkyBVMSzhbNOTzXlC2qTcdz3Whi3TAkJUQGV5UVZVVXUIA)

Comment: This is probably a regression, it works well on TS 4.9 but not in 5.0

Comment: This is caused by [ms/TS#52984](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52984), which changes how narrowings in type guards work when the types are already compatible with each other.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz it sounds like you know. What I don't understand is the fact that also after TS inference it as `{}` also the assertRecord could not change the type anymore. that somehow weird. 

And on the other hand if we early return like in working or workingWithCheck it works since TS may cannot inference that it's not nil (but don't know why since isNil asserts as well). 

I'm happy to read your answer :)

Comment: Sorry I'm not really following your comment. If you want me to respond to it, could you show me with code/playground link what you're talking about?

Comment: Added TS playground in question

I'm wondering why like 15 is displayed as error cause on like 12 we assert that it's `Record<string,any>` but it won't affect inferenced type on like 15 

then in line 43 (fn workingWithCheck) we assert that it's null or undefined and if so we do an early return. So at line 46 I would expect same type then in other function on e.g. line 15. 

Hope I explained it better this time :)

Comment: Okay, now I understand the question, but it seems to be out of scope for the question as asked (that is, it's a followup question and belongs in a new post).  That behavior (custom type guard not narrowing `unknown` to `{}` in the false branch) has not changed between TS4.9 and TS5.0.

Comment: Root question is why function `wontWorking` is not working and why `assertRecord` in this function won't change type 
(and maybe why it's working in the other 2 function examples) 

Im happy to read you answer :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was acknowledged as bug/regression.

See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53379#issuecomment-1476573008).

Comment: Do you want me to write up my own answer, or do you want to flesh this out with a description of the underlying cause etc?

Comment: As you prefer :)

Comment: The fix will land with TS 5.0.3 ! https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53379#event-8827919564